# Using a method from another JSP class

Tags: jsp

Hi Im a complete novice when it coems to using JSP. Im trying to use a method found in a java class from the same project to output the date. The java class looks like this:

```
package my_java_classes;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class myFormattedDate
{

     final String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
     final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.UK);


     public String getFormattedDate()
     {
       String formattedDate = formatter.format( new Date() );
       return formattedDate;
     }


}
```

I've tried looking around and it seems that you can call java classes in JSP like this:

```
<%@ page import = "my_java_classes.myFormattedDate.java" %>
```

But this tells me that "it cannot be resolved." Whats the problem here?

Also correct me if I'm wrong but you can also call other JSP classes using the:

```
<%@ include file='jsp_page_name.jsp'%>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import a class, just use the class identifier.

```
<%@ page import = "<package>.<class>" %>
```

no extra .java is needed.

Comment: Good job, never thought that made a difference

Comment: It's always the details that matter :)